# How can you form unique sets of integers by combining integer arrays with variable sizes in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have any amount of arrays of integers like:

```
[1,9]
[5]
[7]
```

And I want to combine them in such a way that I get sets of numbers like:

```
[1,5,7]
[9,5,7]
```

Another Example INPUT:

```
[1,9]
[3,5]
[7]
[10]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1,3,7,10]
[9,3,7,10]
[1,5,7,10]
[9,5,7,10]
```

I have tried nesting "for" loops but I always seem to get lost and can't get the right iterators I need to pull the right numbers when building the final array. There can be any number of integers in each array, and any number of arrays.

I have tried something like this, but it seems like a deadend:

```
    int[][] allIndexes = {{1, 9},{5},{7}};

    List<Integer> dataset1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //int[] dataset2 = {};

    int i = 0;

    for (int[] indexSet : allIndexes){

        if(indexSet.length > i){
            dataset1.add(indexSet[i]);
        }else{
            dataset1.add(indexSet[0]);
        }
            i++;

    }
    System.out.println(dataset1.toString());
    //System.out.println(dataset2);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I tried searching for others, but I really am not sure if I am defining this correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a variable number of nested loops to enumerate all cases. Thus, recursion is your friend here. The code below will do what you're asking.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[][] allIndexes = {{1, 9},{3,5},{7},{10}};
    List<Integer> dataset1;

    if( allIndexes.length > 0)
    {
        int[] firstIndexes = allIndexes[0];
        for( int i = 0; i < firstIndexes.length; i++)
        {
            dataset1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            dataset1.add( firstIndexes[i]);
            foo( dataset1, allIndexes, 1);
        }
    }
}

public static void foo( List<Integer> dataset1, int[][] allIndexes, int index)
{
    if( index < allIndexes.length)
    {
        int[] indexes = allIndexes[index];

        for( int i = 0; i < indexes.length; i++)
        {
            List<Integer> dataset = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            for( Integer integer : dataset1)
                dataset.add( integer);

            dataset.add( indexes[i]);
            foo( dataset, allIndexes, index+1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append( "[");

        for( int i = 0; i < dataset1.size() - 1; i++)
            sb.append( dataset1.get( i) + ",");

        sb.append( dataset1.get( dataset1.size()-1));
        sb.append( "]");
        System.out.println( sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't haven't even considered calling the method recursively, but I haven't been programming that long. Thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** seems uoyilmaz was faster with his answer

**Edit2** fixed a typo

I think a recursive approach might be worth a try.

You have your *first input array* and all *following input arrays*.

You want to get all combinations of your *following input arrays* and combine each of them with every element from your *first input array*

```
[1,9] // first input array
[5] // following input arrays
[7] // following input arrays
```

.

```
void GetCombinations(int[][] arrays, int startIndex, LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> outLists) {
    // startIndex to high
    if (startIndex >= arrays.length) return;
    int[] firstArray = arrays[startIndex]
    LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> subLists = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
    // get sub-results
    GetCombinations(arrays, startIndex + 1, subLists);
    // combine with firstArray
    if (subLists.size() == 0) {
        subLists.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < subLists.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < firstArray.length; ++j) {
            LinkedList<Integer> temp = new LinkedList<Integer>(subLists.get(i));
            temp.addFirst(firstArray[j]);
            outLists.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

You then call the function with

```
int[][] yourInputArrays = { ... };

LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>> outputLists = new LinkedList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

GetCombinations(yourInputArrays, 0, outputLists);
```

If you are new to programming, the recursive approach might not be intuitive at first, but it is definitely worth looking into it.

Comment: This is an excellent solution, again like my other comment I had not considered recursion. I had an issue with the .addFront method, it says it wasn't part of LinkedList. Thank you again though for the help.

Comment: Well, actually its addFirst... i coded into the browser window, so there is no guarantee that it compiles without any tweak